# Confusion with Embedded questions

Tags: questions, indirect-question

**Do you know? Who is Ann?**
We can say *Do you know who Ann is?* (not "*Do you know who is Ann?*" right?)

So how do I combine the followings?

**Do you know? What is right or wrong?**

***Do you know what right or wrong is?*** or ***Do you know what is right or wrong?***
Which one is correct? 
Same with this too ***I don't know what right or wrong is?*** or ***I don't know what is right or wrong?***. Which one is correct?
I think it is the second one that is correct because **What is right or wrong?** is a subject question. Please correct me otherwise. But I  don't feel that the first one is wrong as well. It just feels like there are two different meanings. Am I right?

**Who told him? What was inside my book?**

***Who told him what was inside your book?***
***Who told him what your book was inside?***
Again with the above, I think it is the first one which is correct right? The second one feels really awkward.

Please correct me, I am confused. When I check them on online grammar checkers, they didn't show any errors at all for all the above variations. Thank you.

Comment: "I don't know what right or wrong is" and "I don't know what is right or wrong" mean different things. The first means you have no moral compass, the second means you're not sure which course to take. Both are grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: @Robusto I would like to know the grammar rule behind this? As I have learned unless it a subject question we need to change the word order when we form the sentence in embedded questions. So if we can use it in both ways can you please explain that rule a bit? Thank you.